# Using "larger than" / "smaller than" on a vector with both numerical values and characters

Tags: r

This seems like the most silly question ever, but I cannot figure out what is going on..

I have data as follows:

```
test <- c("A", 1, 2)    
out <- rep("ON", 3)
```

I want to replace values that have a numerical value larger than 1 (so 2 should be `OFF`).

If I do:

```
out[test > 1] <- "OFF"   
out
```

I get:

```
[1] "OFF" "ON"  "OFF"
```

Because apparently `"A" > 1 = TRUE`

If I do

```
out[as.numeric(test > 1)] <- "OFF"
```

I get:

```
[1] "OFF" "ON"  "ON"
```

Even though `as.numeric(test > 1)` is:

```
[1] 1 0 1
```

and `as.numeric("A")` is `NA`, and `NA > 1` is `NA`.

What is the right way to get these values?

## EDIT

Because the function that I am using throws an error if there is a warning, I tried to combine the solution of akrun and Dmitry (because that solution throws a warning).

However, for some reason:

```
test <- c("25", "38", "40", "38", "207", "16", "31", "18", "22", "20", 
"3", "19", "4", "43", "20", "15", "21", "36", "36", "23", "33", 
"31", "48")
grepl("^[0-9.]+$", test) & test < 10
```

is

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: You may need `grepl("^[0-9.]+$", test) & test > 1`

Comment: @akrun  I am trying to find a solution that does not throw a warning (see EDIT), but I am not succesful. Do you know why your solution has this behaviour?

Comment: R is correct in throwing a warning, since R vectors are type-homogenous. To suppress the warning, wrap the call in question with `suppressWarnings`

Comment: @DmitryZotikov Thanks, I figured out that I could just suppress the warning. So my question is essentially solved (and I accepted your answer). But I am still kind of curious why my solution in the EDIT does not work.

Comment: @Tom it wouldn't throw warning compared to `as.numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
test <- c("A", 1, 2)    
out <- rep("ON", 3)
idx <- as.numeric(test) > 1
is.na(idx) <- FALSE
out[idx] <- 'OFF'
out
```

```
[1] "ON"  "ON" "OFF"
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach may be to use a simple `ifelse` statement on the `test` vector without the need for the `out` vector:

```
ifelse(test %in% "2", "OFF","ON")

# [1] "ON"  "ON"  "OFF"
```

This would only work for the test dataset you provided, but if there was a limit to what the values greater than 2 could be you could expand it:

```
test <- c("A", 1, 2, 999)
ifelse(test %in% as.character(2:1000), "OFF","ON")

# [1] "ON"  "ON"  "OFF" "OFF"
```